# Include fileson python

Tags: python

If I had two files on the same folder
this is functions.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def foo():
    print "bar"
```

and this is main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import functions

functions.foo()
```

If I want to use the foo() function I have yo call it functions.foo() ,there is a way yo call it only foo()?

Comment: `from functions import foo`. Although remember that [Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
from functions import foo
```

But it may cause some problems if you're working with lots of files and you might come with two functions with the same name.

I'd stick with the *ugly* way you had in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one of

```
import functions as foo_functions
from functions import foo as bar
```

In example.py

```
import sys as my_sys
from sys import argv as arrrrg

print arrrrg
print my_sys.argv
```

Running `$python example.py foo bar` produces

```
['test.py', 'foo', 'bar']
['test.py', 'foo', 'bar']
```